# Worklight Direct update is not working for Windows App

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Direct Update is not working for my Worklight App while for android and ios the feature is working as expected.

Application Descriptor

```
 <windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
       <uuid>xxxx-3235-xx-a24e-fdxxxxx6ac</uuid>
       <pushSender/>
       <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="true"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false"/>
        <productId>xxxxxxx-7b4a-xxxxx-b387-078e8fa0c3d5</productId>
        <applicationId>NextMobile</applicationId>
    </security>
  </windowsPhone8>
```

authenticationConfig.xml

```
 <customSecurityTest name="Adapters-securityTest">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="YesAuthRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true"         step="2"/>

    </customSecurityTest>
```

Comment: What version of Worklight/MobileFirst are we talking?

Comment: IBM mobile first version 7.0 with fix pack   7.0.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201603212143

Comment: Direct update feature is not working in windows

Comment: So you make some changes to your application, deploy the new wlapp to the server, you application connects to the server and you do not see direct update coming to your device ? Or do you see the direct update pop-up but then it fails or update ? What exactly is the "issue" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom security test defined with Direct Update (`<test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>`), but you did not apply this security test to the Windows Phone environment (`<windowsPhone8 version="1.0">`). Try applying it.

Other than this you are not explaining how the feature is failing for you. By not even getting an update notification, or getting it back it fails downloading, or fails extracting and so on.